# OOP Programming in MATLAB with stored values that also change (like an incrementer)

Tags: matlab, oop

I am relatively new to object-oriented programming in MATLAB, so maybe I just don't understand the philosophy behind it, but I cannot seem to figure this out. I want to have a set of object properties. One property is statically created on object creation, and the other is an incrementing value which stores information relevant to the object's use.

```
classdef MyClass
    properties
       max_inc; % Statically created cap on the incrementer
       incr;    % The incrementer
    end
    methods
        % Constructor
        function c = MyClass(set_max)
            c.max_inc = set_max;
            c.incr = 1;
        end

        % Function to do some stuff
        function value = Next(c)
            % Do some stuff
            set(c, 'incr', c.incr + 1);
        end

        % Set function which is causing me trouble
        function c = set.incr(c, value)
            if(value <= c.max_inc)
                c.incr = value;
            else
                c.incr = 1;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I was able to make a work-around which doesn't error out by getting rid of the set function and implementing the `Next(c)` function as:

```
% Function to do some stuff
function value = Next(c)
    % Do some stuff
    curr_inc = c.incr;
    if(curr_inc < c.max_inc)
        c.incr = curr_inc + 1;
    else
        c.incr = 1;
    end
end
```

While this runs, it does not actually seem to change the value of `incr` when `Next(c)` is called (it always thinks `incr` is the starting value). I don't want to make `incr` dependent because it does need to store its value so I know how many times it has been incremented previously, and I cannot make this a handle object because I need more than one to be active at the same time (unless I am completely misunderstanding how handle objects work). Is there not a way to do this? This seems like it should be a really easy thing to do with an object.

EDIT: I forgot to explicitly ask not only if there is a way to make this work, but to do so where the incrementer logic is handled in the set function like I originally tried (it seems like that is the more logical place for it, and will make more readable code).

Comment: `Next` must return the object `c`, and be called as: `c = Next(c)`. Otherwise make the class inherit from `handle`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would implement such a class:

```
classdef MyClass < handle
    properties (Access = protected)
       max_inc
    end
    properties (SetAccess = protected)
       incr
    end
    methods
        function obj = MyClass(set_max)
            obj.max_inc = set_max;
            obj.incr = 1;
        end
        function next(obj)
            obj.incr = obj.incr + 1;
            if obj.incr > obj.max_inc
                obj.incr = 1;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Example usage:

```
>> c = MyClass(5)
c = 
  MyClass with properties:

    incr: 1

>> for i=1:7, c.next(); end
>> c
c = 
  MyClass with properties:

    incr: 3
```

Note that I chose to create a **handle class** (by inheriting from the abstract `handle` class) [as opposed to](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html) a **value class**. The way you had it defined, you had to return the modified object each time you called `Next`, because value classes are passed by copy (not by reference).

Also note that I chose to reduced the accessibility of properties (it is usually a good practice to hide the internal implementation of your class).

So now the `next` method is responsible for incrementing the counter, and wrapping the value back to `1` when it exceeds the max limit.

Of course having a handle class does not stop you from creating multiple objects, each having its own separate state:

```
>> c1 = MyClass(5); c2 = MyClass(10);
>> for i=1:3, c1.next(); end
>> for i=1:6, c2.next(); end

>> c1
c1 = 
  MyClass with properties:

    incr: 4
>> c2
c2 = 
  MyClass with properties:

    incr: 7
```

The only way you have two variables referring to the same object is if you assign references that way:

```
>> c3 = c1; c3.next();
>> c1
c1 = 
  MyClass with properties:

    incr: 5
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment; I must have misunderstood handle classes. The documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/mutable-handle-vs-immutable-value-enumeration-members.html) makes the claim that changing the value in one will also change the value in future instantiated classes; is this only for enumerated handle classes, then?

Comment: yes, that page is specifically talking about enumeration, whether to use value-based or handle-based class

Comment: Comming from an OO language myself, I nearly always inherit matlab classes from handle as this causes things to behave as expected.

Comment: @PeterM: absolutely, I think handle-based classes should have been the default. I almost never used value classes, except when subclassing MATLAB builtin types (`classdef MyDouble < double`) or when defining enums